# Embedding Altair htmls in google sites, how to `mark_image` using private google drive links?

Tags: google-drive-api, altair, vega-lite, google-sites-2016

I am trying to embed an interactive plot made using `Altair` into google-site. In this plot, I want to interactively display an image at a time that is stored on google-drive. When I gave this an attempt, `mark_image` failed silently, presumably because it did not read the image. This is not a surprise because google-drive images were private. With publically shared images I won't have this issue. For the purpose of this plot, I would like to keep the images private. Plus, there are a lot of images in total (~1K), so I probably should not encode them in data/bytes. I suspect that would probably make my HTML file very big and slow. Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

I wonder if `mark_image` could read the images from the google-drive links, probably using a "reader" of some sort (an upstream JS or python library), and then feed the read image to `mark_image`. If anybody has experience with this, solutions/suggestions/workarounds would be greatly helpful.

##### Here's a demo code to test this:

**Case 1: Publically accessible image (no problem).** Displayed using `mark_image`, saved in HTML format.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
path="https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png"
source = pd.DataFrame([{"x": 0, "y": 0, "img": path},])

chart=alt.Chart(source).mark_image(width=100,height=100,).encode(x='x',y='y',url='img')
chart.save('test.html')
```

[image]

Then I embed the HTML in a google-site (private, not shared to the public), using this option [image] and then paste the content of the HTML file in the `Embed code` tab.

**Case 2: Image on Google-drive (problem!).** The case of an image stored on google-drive (private, not shared to the public).

```
# Please use the code above with `path` variable generated like this:
file_id='' # google drive file id
path=f"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={file_id}"
```

In this case, apparently `mark_image` fails silently and the image is not shown on the plot. ​

Answer (score 0):

After searching for an optimal solution, I decided to rely on a sort of a workaround of encoding the images in data/bytes. This eliminates the issue of reading the URLs from google drive, which I could not find a solution for.
Encoding images in data/bytes, as I suspected, made the HTML big in size, however, surprisingly (to me) not slow to load at all. I guess that's the best thing I could do for what I wanted to do.

In the example below, `get_data` function obtains the data/bytes of an image. I put that into a column of the dataframe that is taken by `Altair` as input.

```
def plot_(images_from):
    import altair as alt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    np.random.seed(0)
    n_objects = 20
    n_times = 50
    # Create one (x, y) pair of metadata per object
    locations = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': range(n_objects),
        'x': np.random.randn(n_objects),
        'y': np.random.randn(n_objects)
    })
    def get_data(p):
        import base64
        with open(p, "rb") as f:
            return "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()
    import urllib.request
    if images_from=='url':
        l1=[f"https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/{k}.png" for k in ['ffox','7zip','gimp']]
    elif images_from=='data':
        l1=[get_data(urllib.request.urlretrieve(f"https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/{k}.png",f'/tmp/{k}.png')[0]) for k in ['ffox','7zip','gimp']]

    np.random.seed(0)
    locations['img']=np.random.choice(l1, size=len(locations))

    # Create a 50-element time-series for each object
    timeseries = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n_times, n_objects).cumsum(0),
                            columns=locations['id'],
                            index=pd.RangeIndex(0, n_times, name='time'))

    # Melt the wide-form timeseries into a long-form view
    timeseries = timeseries.reset_index().melt('time')

    # Merge the (x, y) metadata into the long-form view
    timeseries['id'] = timeseries['id'].astype(int)  # make merge not complain
    data = pd.merge(timeseries, locations, on='id')

    # Data is prepared, now make a chart

    selector = alt.selection_single(empty='none', fields=['id'])

    base = alt.Chart(data).properties(
        width=250,
        height=250
    ).add_selection(selector)

    points = base.mark_point(filled=True, size=200).encode(
        x='mean(x)',
        y='mean(y)',
        color=alt.condition(selector, 'id:O', alt.value('lightgray'), legend=None),
    )

    timeseries = base.mark_line().encode(
        x='time',
        y=alt.Y('value', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-15, 15))),
        color=alt.Color('id:O', legend=None)
    ).transform_filter(
        selector
    )

    images=base.mark_image(filled=True, size=200).encode(
        x='x',
        y='y',
        url='img',
    ).transform_filter(
        selector
    )

    chart=points | timeseries | images
    chart.save(f'test/chart_images_{images_from}.html')

# generate htmls
plot_(images_from='url') # generate the HTML using URLs
plot_(images_from='data') # generate the HTML using data/bytes
```

The HTML made using the data was ~78 times bigger than the one made using URLs (~12Mb vs ~0.16Kb), but not noticeably slower.

**Update**: As I later found out google site does not allow embedding an HTML file of more than 1Mb size. So in the end, encoding the images did not really help.

[image]

Comment: Update: the size of the html file increases exponentially when many images are encoded stored in it. One of my html file became ~140Mb (even while using low res. JPEG images). When I tried to paste the content of the html into the `embed code` window of google site, the google site became unresponsive. So there are clear limitations to this workaround approach.

Comment: Update: As an alternative to google-sites which allows embedding of upto 1Mb of HTML code, I tried Silex (https://www.silex.me/) with dropbox to store data. There too, size of the embedded HTML is an issue. Silex allowed embedding of HTML of size upto 5Mb.